# Self-hosted alternative to Pastebin

Tags: gratis, web-apps, api, self-hosted, pastebin

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) is a service that allows you to "paste" any text and share it with others, publicly or privately. I am in need of a piece of self-hosted software that does exactly what pastebin does, but without the need of a 3rd party.

To give you some context, I am attempting to create an error reporting/support service for my bukkit plugin and I need something that not only uploads a log file, but also can be shared with the user. Pastebin's API would be a great thing for this, but they limit the data to just 500kb and I would rather not send personal information through a 3rd party. I **need** this software to have a built in API so that I can submit data via POST and have it return a link to the paste, just like what pastebin does.

Requirements:

- It must be self-hosted
- It must be gratis (free) and it would be preferred if it was floss (open source) but that's not a requirement
- It must have a **built in** API so I may submit my data

  - The API must be able to get data (the text I am sending it), and return the link to the paste
- It is preferable if its made with php and be integrated into my website (I don't have tons of RAM on my VPS, so I don't really want to run additional services if I don't have to)
- Syntax highlighting would be pretty nifty, but not required

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Stikked](https://github.com/claudehohl/Stikked) will do the trick [(example)](http://paste.scratchbook.ch/).

> Stikked is an Open-Source PHP Pastebin, with the aim of keeping a simple and easy to use user interface.
>
> Stikked allows you to easily share code with anyone you wish. Based on the original Stikked with lots of bugfixes and improvements.

Features:

- Self-hosted
- Free
- Developed with php
- Has a built-in API that accepts POST data and returns the link. Even has the ability to secure the API with an optional API key
- Syntax highlighting (can select the language either via web interface or through API)
- Expiring pastes
- Themes
- Integration with [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) (especially love this feature)
- Anti-spam features
- Ability to "reply" to a paste

I must say I am very pleased with this software. Works just like I wanted it to.

Comment: Hmm... plain text doesn't use fixed width font.  Annoying.

Answer (score 6):

[**Sticky Notes**](http://www.sayakbanerjee.com/sticky-notes/) which is used by the [Fedora pastebin](http://paste.fedoraproject.org)<sup>*</sup>:

- BSD 2-clause license
- runs on PHP and MySQL
- has syntax highlighting
- has an [API](http://sayakb.github.io/sticky-notes/pages/api/) (by the way, Fedora also has a command-line client, [fpaste](https://fedorahosted.org/fpaste/) which is written in Python)
- [add-on services](http://sayakb.github.io/sticky-notes/pages/services/): project Honeypot integration, goog.gl URL shortener, Google Analytics, Google oAuth 2.0, Akismet, project pastebins (someproject.yoursite.com), CLI configuration editor

<sub><sup>*</sup> You might find useful the ansible [role](http://infrastructure.fedoraproject.org/cgit/ansible.git/tree/roles/paste) used by the Fedora infrastructure team for deploying it.</sub>