# Online host to upload log files

Tags: web-apps, logs, document-management

Often I have logfiles to questions or answers on StackExchange-pages but the logs are to large to post them on the side. So I am looking for a solution to upload the log at an other place and link to it.

Here is an example logfile that is hard to read:

> Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx plesk sendmail[20876]: handlers_stderr: SKIP Oct 
>   3 21:22:03 xxx plesk sendmail[20876]: SKIP during call 'check-quota'
>   handler Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail-queue-handlers[20880]: Handlers
>   Filter before-queue for qmail started ... Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-queue-handlers[20880]: from=info@xyz.com Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-queue-handlers[20880]: to=admin@example.com Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-queue-handlers[20880]: starter: submitter[20881] exited normally
>   Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail: 1412364123.362381 new msg 27009050 Oct  3
>   21:22:03 xxx qmail: 1412364123.362400 info msg 27009050: bytes 734
>   from  qp 20881 uid 10006 Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail:
>   1412364123.367011 starting delivery 109: msg 27009050 to remote admin@example.com Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail: 1412364123.367038 status:
>   local 0/10 remote 1/20 Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-remote-handlers[20882]: Handlers Filter before-remote for qmail
>   started ... Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail-remote-handlers[20882]:
>   from=info@xyz.com Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail-remote-handlers[20882]:
>   to=admin@example.com Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail: 1412364123.785542
>   delivery 109: failure:
>   2a00:1450:4013:0c00:0000:0000:0000:001a_failed_after_I_sent_the_message./Remote_host_said:*550-5.7.1*[2a01:238:4209:4d00:b1bf:19bc:7d93:971______12]_Our_system_has/550-5.7.1_detected_that_this_message_is_likely_unsolicited_mail._To_reduce_the/550-5.7.1_amount_of_spam_sent_to_Gmail,_this_message_has_been_blocked._Please/550-5.7.1_visit/550-5.7.1_http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131_for/550_5.7.1_more_information.*e5si3014231wij.93*-_gsmtp/
>   Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail: 1412364123.785573 status: local 0/10 remote
>   0/20 Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail-queue-handlers[20883]: Handlers Filter
>   before-queue for qmail started ... Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-queue-handlers[20883]: from= Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-queue-handlers[20883]: to=info@xyz.com Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-queue-handlers[20883]: Unable to get sender domain by sender
>   mailname Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail-queue-handlers[20883]: Unable to
>   get sender domain by sender mailname Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-queue-handlers[20883]: handlers_stderr: SKIP Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-queue-handlers[20883]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
>   Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail-queue-handlers[20883]: starter:
>   submitter[20885] exited normally Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail:
>   1412364123.849243 bounce msg 27009050 qp 20883 Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail: 1412364123.849263 end msg 27009050 Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail:
>   1412364123.849886 new msg 27009083 Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail: 1412364123.849903 info msg 27009083: bytes 1718 from <> qp 20885 uid 2522 Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail: 1412364123.854642 starting delivery
>   110: msg 27009083 to remote info@xyz.com Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail:
>   1412364123.854667 status: local 0/10 remote 1/20 Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail-remote-handlers[20886]: Handlers Filter before-remote for qmail
>   started ... Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx qmail-remote-handlers[20886]:
>   from=postmaster@xxx.stratoserver.net Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-remote-handlers[20886]: to=info@xyz.com Oct  3 21:22:03 xxx
>   qmail-remote-handlers[20886]: Unable to get sender domain by sender
>   mailname Oct  3 21:22:04 xxx qmail: 1412364124.326793 delivery 110:
>   success:
>   213.165.67.120_accepted_message./Remote_host_said:_250_Requested_mail_action_okay,_completed:_id=0MIcxY-1XXwZA0iDo-002K1j/
>   Oct  3 21:22:04 xxx qmail: 1412364124.326826 status: local 0/10 remote
>   0/20 Oct  3 21:22:04 xxx qmail: 1412364124.326833 end msg 27009083 Oct
>   3 21:22:28 xxx courier-imapd: Connection, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1] Oct  3
>   21:22:28 xxx courier-imapd: LOGOUT, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1], rcvd=12,
>   sent=365 Oct  3 21:22:28 xxx courier-imaps: Connection,
>   ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1] Oct  3 21:22:28 xxx courier-imaps: LOGOUT,
>   ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1], rcvd=12, sent=356 Oct  3 21:22:28 xxx
>   courier-pop3d: Connection, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1] Oct  3 21:22:28 xxx
>   courier-pop3d: LOGOUT, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1] Oct  3 21:22:28 xxx
>   courier-pop3d: Disconnected, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1] Oct  3 21:22:28 xxx
>   courier-pop3s: Connection, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1] Oct  3 21:22:28 xxx
>   courier-pop3s: LOGOUT, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1] Oct  3 21:22:28 xxx
>   courier-pop3s: Disconnected, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]

Comment: Do you look for a hosted or a self-hosted solution?

Comment: @unor for a hosted solution where you can be sure that is stays there for some time (ideal of cause would be for ever).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a *pastebin* web application.

Most of them offer the same features: paste some content, select syntax highlighting (if any), select if it should be private/public, and when it should be deleted automatically (if at all).

A popular service is [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/), which, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin#History), exists since 2002. While there naturally can be no guarantuee that a non-self-hosted service stays in business (or suddenly deletes all content, etc.), about 12 years of operation is quite a time.

Another service is [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/). While not so old as pastebin.com, it’s provided by [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) which some may trust because of its prominence.

(And if you should inted to self-host in the future, have a look at this question: [Self-hosted alternative to Pastebin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/self-hosted-alternative-to-pastebin))